# why did my legend disppear in seaborn histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am new to python visualization and i am trying to plot some movie data

here is my code for plotting histogram to show the gross of different genres:

```
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,10))
ax = sns.histplot(movie[movie['genre'].isin(list_movie_genre_gross)],
                x="score", bins=70, multiple='stack', hue='genre'
              ,hue_order=list_movie_genre_gross)
```

and the output is [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFkur.png

May I know how to customize the legend (like editing the font size of the text, position)? Thanks in advance

Comment: i want to make to font size of the legend box larger
and I don't know what is the appropriate way to do so

Comment: @brokenjj9 I recommend reframing your question in that light

Comment: This is an issue with seaborn.  At seaborn's github a workaround is suggested which reuses some of the internal legend variables. See [this comment](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2280#issuecomment-692350136)

Comment: Seaborn 11.2 should have a new function `sns.move_legend` that lets you nit only move but also change many other parameters. See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/2643

Comment: Thanks u guys so much!! i solved it